# Sum of three columns which is populated using case statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get sum of devicePoint, osPoint, browserPoint which is populated using case statement inside select in sql.Here is my code

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN device='Default' THEN 1
        ELSE 5
    END AS devicePoint,
    CASE
        WHEN operating_system='Default' THEN 1
        ELSE 3
    END AS osPoint,
    CASE
        WHEN browser='Default' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END AS browserPoint,
    (devicePoint + osPoint + browserPoint) as 'Total'
FROM mytable
WHERE 
 (
    (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Ios' AND browser='Firefox')
    OR
    (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Ios' AND browser='Default')
    OR 
    (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Firefox')
    OR 
    (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Default')
    OR 
    (device = 'Default' AND operating_system='Ios' AND browser='Default')
    OR 
    (device = 'Default' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Firefox')
    OR 
    (device = 'Default' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Default')
)
```

Comment: You need to use a subquery for the calculation or repeat the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing an answer because you can simplify the `where` clause because MySQL supports tuples.  The logic would look like this:

```
select t.*,
       (devicePoint + osPoint + browserPoint) as 'Total'
from (select (case when device = 'Default' then 1 else 5 end) as devicePoint,
             (case when operating_system = 'Default' then 1 else 3 end) as osPoint,
             (case when browser = 'Default' then 1 else 2 end) as browserPoint        
      from mytable t
      where (device, operating_system, browser) in
                ( ('Desktop', 'Ios', 'Firefox'),
                  ('Desktop', 'Ios', 'Default'),
                  . . .
                )
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    devicePoint,
    osPoint,
    browserPoint,
    (devicePoint + osPoint + browserPoint) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN device = 'Default' THEN 1 ELSE 5 END AS devicePoint,
        CASE WHEN operating_system = 'Default' THEN 1 ELSE 3 END AS osPoint,
        CASE WHEN browser = 'Default' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS browserPoint
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Ios' AND browser='Firefox') OR
        (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Ios' AND browser='Default') OR
        (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Firefox') OR
        (device = 'Desktop' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Default') OR
        (device = 'Default' AND operating_system='Ios' AND browser='Default') OR
        (device = 'Default' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Firefox') OR
        (device = 'Default' AND operating_system='Default' AND browser='Default')
) t;
```

It isn't possible to refer to your three aliases in the same `SELECT` in which they were defined.  But, they are available if you use the subquery approach above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest **WHERE** clause for you.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN device='Default' THEN 1
        ELSE 5
    END AS devicePoint,
    CASE
        WHEN operating_system='Default' THEN 1
        ELSE 3
    END AS osPoint,
    CASE
        WHEN browser='Default' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END AS browserPoint,
    (devicePoint + osPoint + browserPoint) as 'Total'
FROM mytable
WHERE 
 (device IN ('Desktop','Default') AND operating_system IN ('Ios','Default') AND browser IN ('Firefox','Default'))
```